# Is it possible to call GC in Android?

Tags: android, memory

I am wondering if there is a way to call gc from code, hopefully to free some memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can request it with

```
System.gc();
```

Although the important note is this is only a request.  There is no guarantee that the GC will run.

Comment: oops!!! There is no guarantee that the GC will run. I was not aware of it. thanks